# How do I revert updates to get to a usable GUI

Tags: 14.04, bash

I've been using 14.04 for a while and everything seems running smooth,until last night I downloaded updates.Afterwards I restarted and a message like a reminder or new email type message popped up saying I was locked out of my account(I was online and I think the message revered to my email or Ubuntu one account,sad to say It would only go as far as the login window after which it hangs with my screensaver.I am new to ubuntu and don't know the terminal so good,the tty I get to when pressing ctrl + alt f2 can't log in either,it says login incorrect.I can only get in when I drop to the shell in the grub recovery menu.Can somebody talk me through a procedure.

Comment: I'm confused, is the "locked out of my account" relevant? What is wrong with the GUI?

Comment: It freezes after login,with a window of which the resolution is very high,because everything is enlarged and the edges around are cut off,so I think its something to do with the graphics card,which is a nvidia geforce gt630

Comment: Can you add your laptop model etc.  I believe you have an Optimus based laptop, but I need the model to confirm....

Answer (score 0):

To Get a Terminal that isn't graphical:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>

To kill Xorg all together while you troubleshoot, in the terminal window after login type

```
sudo systemctl stop gdm (GNOME/Unity)
sudo systemctl stop kdm (KDE)
```

To revert packages, see this [Forum Post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1804985).  It may not be a package, so:
`nano -w /var/log/XOrg.0.log` to see if the last successful X Server completeted.

Comment: I did inspect /var/log/Xorg.0.log but with less,but I don't know what to look for.